# From URL to Document object

Tags: java, xml, rss

I would like to transform a feed to a Document object.
I tried the following code but it seems it's not working with a real feed (uri = null), but it works with an XML file which is already in my computer.

The transform function :

```
public static Document obtainDocument(String feedurl) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(feedurl);
    doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
    ...Exceptions...
    return doc;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure that the URL is right, I use:

```
String feedurl = "http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Pressecitron";
```

I tried to use the following code too:

```
public static Document obtainDocument(String feedurl) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(feedurl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
    ...

    return doc;
}
```

which seems to not works better

And my first version of parser used a String too, but my mate wants me to use a Document (if the connection doesn't work). It worked with the String if I remember well.

Comment: Actually the URL you provided (http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Pressecitron) does **NOT** point to an XML document. The method [DocumentBuilder#parse(InputStream is)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29) parses the content of the given InputStream **as an XML document** and returns a new DOM Document object.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me...make sure that the `feedurl` is correct within the `obtainDocument` method...

Comment: @informatik01 Actually, if you try and read it via the XML API it is an RSS feed, it appears to be smart enough to know when you're using a browser and redirects you (I think) - in any case, I was able to down a RSS, XML document without issue (and yes, that was my first thought too)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm, maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all the possible ways of using the `parse()` method ?
Are you sure the URI / URL is correct ?

From the method that you have, you get the `feedURL` as a `String`. You can directly pass it to the `parse()` method and see if that works.